# Zend Framework 2 – type hinting in constructor – IDE complains about type

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpstorm, type-hinting

In a Zend Framework 2 module, I use a closure as factory:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'ZendSkeletonModule\Controller\Skeleton' => function(AbstractPluginManager $pm) {
            return new Controller\SkeletonController($pm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
        },
    ],
],
```

While this works without any problems, my IDE (PHP Storm) complains at `$pm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')` with the following message:

> Expected \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, got array|object.
>   Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared.

That is because in the controller, I use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface` as a type hint, I get that.

But why does PHP Storm complain, I don't see anything wrong here? Also, the code works fine, so I am a bit puzzled. Do I need to add some kind of special comment or something to 'help' the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the EntityManager to a variable with an annotation that PhpStorm's static analysis can use. The `get` method on its own is opaque to it:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
// snip
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'ZendSkeletonModule\Controller\Skeleton' => function(AbstractPluginManager $pm) {
            /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
            $entityManager = $pm->getServiceLocator()->get(EntityManager::class);
            return new Controller\SkeletonController($entityManager);
        },
    ],
],
```

A couple additional suggestions:

1. Rather than using a closure, use a concrete factory class. This is because closures cannot be opcode cached, and also your config array cannot be cached if it contains closures.
2. A small thing, but assuming PHP 5.5+, consider using `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::class` like I did in the example above, instead of a string literal for the get method on the ServiceLocator.

Comment: PhpStorm also supports factory methods like this inside `PHPSTORM_META\$STATIC_METHOD_TYPES` (see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata)

Comment: Thanks man! You really helped me out with that issue – it was bugging me for weeks. Also your additional hints are great, thanks again.